# wxPanel show function does not work inside wxThreads

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, messagebox

```
#include "MessageBoxThread.h"

MessageBoxThread::MessageBoxThread(NfcUIConfirmProcessUC* dialogUC)
{
    this->dialogUC = dialogUC;
}

MessageBoxThread::~MessageBoxThread(void)
{
}

void* MessageBoxThread::Entry()
{
    this->dialogUC->Show(true);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The question being exactly??? Also what errors are you getting? Also, you can't show GUI elements in any other thread besides the GUI thread.

Comment: Maybe you could add a little description of the problem you are having?

Comment: As I know from Qt, you can't execute any GUI related functions in non-GUI threads. I assume in wxWidgets it is similar. You man pass a flag to GUI thread, and execute Show-method there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote from the wxThread [docs](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_thread.html#thread_secondary):

> GUI calls, such as those to a wxWindow or wxBitmap are explicitly not safe at all in secondary threads and could end your application prematurely. This is due to several reasons, including the underlying native API and the fact that wxThread does not run a GUI event loop similar to other APIs as MFC. [...] the recommended way is to simply process the GUI calls in the main thread through an event that is posted by wxQueueEvent()

So basically the best way to solve this problem is rather than calling Show to create an event (for example a wxThreadEvent) post it back to the dialog and then using an event macro or bind connect it to a dialog member which shows the dialog.